# Create Timestamp in TCP raw socket

Tags: sockets, timestamp

I need to implement a TCP raw socket with the timestamp as an option on the TCP Header.
Analyzing packets with the timestamps set in wireshark, I couldn't figure out how the timestamps are created (it is not related to the initial time of midnight 1/1/1970 at all). Does anyone know how to create a valid timestamp? I need to communicate with a server that requires this tag. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? What you saw and what is required?